# Passband filter before Hilbert transform

Tags: phase, speech, hilbert-transform, analytic-signal

I have a .wav file of human speech sampled at 48kHz. Before making the analytic signal with:

hilbert(s_real)

lets say in range 200 - 3,500 Hz, I probably need to do pass-band filtering, say 300 - 3,400 Hz. Does it matter for subsequent Hilbert transform, what type of filter is applied: Bessel, Butterworth, Chebyshev or Elliptic?

Comment: well, you get different signals when applying different filters? I'm not sure what you're asking here. What are you worried about?

Comment: one of the options of remez exchange is a hilbert transform